# Error configuring Duende IdentityServer 6 with Docker

Tags: docker, duende, identityserver6

I've been fighting with a problem for some days. It's related to connecting containers using Duende IdentityServer as IdP.

My system consists of:

- a Duende IdentityServer 6 container (idp)
- a client application in React using BFF pattern (using Duende.BFF) (cli)

The application must run in HTTP and in front of it I will have a balancer with TLS, so internally it must use HTTP.

I've created a docker compose file to run the application using this configuration (simplify version):

```
services:
  idp:
    build: ./<Identity-folder>
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    environment:
      - ...
  cli:
    build: ./<Client-folder>
    ports:
      - "5002:80"
    environment:
      - AUTHORITY=http://idp
      - REQUIREHTTPSMETADATA=false
```

When I hit login from the client app I get the following error:

```
cli-1  | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ResponseCookies[1]
cli-1  |       The cookie '.AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce.CfDJ8F-b95I6wSdJpaLTwuHEFX_Az_Khhb2aOJ7MvLT7345b_zt-x9cVcuNtMmP6mAWRwuExmttQyom3HinNzSetJ19_I766jjXwwT4S9mdj9uj1qlrnd_fxy401UYZmdIwak7aeuoC5Re98QlcaH5V48Uahv_Hcvo6RjQEEigx9eCqY-UM3oBAuVA2nLhvxt8W1KV6WS9lvN2TeL1jVzZrSuCXAj7nJAvlgT1ovdTxN_3K4_m3Q60kYrrceGCz8RYhiftDLF5yNGIsDssQHFz0ReBo' has set 'SameSite=None' and must also set 'Secure'.
cli-1  | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ResponseCookies[1]
cli-1  |       The cookie '.AspNetCore.Correlation.yYUba7j9MG6EzwnzfS00gE9OOov4yFFE742naXtZFoY' has set 'SameSite=None' and must also set 'Secure'.
```

The relevant configuration in program.cs of the IdP is as follows:

```
...
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var cert = SigningCredentialConfiguration.GetFromFile(gConfig);

builder.Services
    .AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

        options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;

        options.KeyManagement.Enabled = false;

        options.Authentication.CheckSessionCookieSameSiteMode = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    })
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(InMemoryConfig.IdentityResources)
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(InMemoryConfig.ApiScopes)
    .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfig.Clients)
    .AddAspNetIdentity<AppUser>()
    .AddSigningCredential(cert);
...
```

The InMemoryConfig.Clients is as follows:

```
...
new Client
{
    ClientId = "client",
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc", "http://cli/signin-oidc" },
    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "http://localhost:5002/signout-oidc",
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", ... },
    AllowPlainTextPkce = true,
},
...
```

And the program.cs of the client app is as follows:

```
...
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        options.DefaultSignOutScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("cookie", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "__Host-bff";
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict; // Strict

        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = gConfig.Authority;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = gConfig.RequireHttpsMetadata;

        options.ClientId = "client";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.ResponseMode = "query";
      
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.MapInboundClaims = false;
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    });
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use strict for the session cookie because it was "set" by a different site (IdentityServer). You need to use LAX.

```
  options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict; // Strict
```

Also, cookies won't work if you use HTTP; you must use HTTPS for successful OIDC in the browser.

Comment: Thanks Tore! I agree with what you say.
I think that is the right way of doing things, and that make sense to me. 
Now I'm trying to configure the certificate but that is another story.
Thanks for your replay!

Comment: Feel free to post your new problem as a question here on SO.